# Why forwarding-only local caching bind9 instance queries 'root' zone servers?

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I am configuring local forwarding-only DNS(bind9) server.
Have following configuration:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes; /* So that server could answer queries about domains its is not authoritative for. */
    allow-query { homeclients; };

    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
    forward only;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on port 53 {
        127.0.0.1;
        192.168.1.33;
    };
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

But when I do:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 ubuntu.com +trace
```

I get:

```
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
.           3600000 IN  NS  J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
...
.           3600000 IN  NS  K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
;; Received 811 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 0 ms

ubuntu.com.     3600    IN  A   91.189.94.40
;; Received 55 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET) in 1 ms
```

*dig* gets its information from local *bind* instance that should, according to my configuration, forward all queries to Google's DNS servers.
But it also asks root servers...

Why forwarding-only DNS server asks 'root' servers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missunderstand the way that dig's trace mode actually works. Looking at dig's man page you get the following information:

```
+[no]trace
  Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name servers
  for the name being looked up. Tracing is disabled by default. When
  tracing is enabled, dig makes iterative queries to resolve the name
  being looked up. It will follow referrals from the root servers,
  showing the answer from each server that was used to resolve the
  lookup.

  If @server is also specified, it affects only the initial query for
  the root zone name servers.
```

Especially the last part makes it clear, that `dig +trace @server` will ask server about the root name servers, and will then take over and iterate the next level's nameservers itself.

However, I understand your wondering - I had to look it up myself ;)